# There are no SQL Server instances or shared features that can be updated on this computer

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sql-server

I am trying to install SQL server 2008 r2 on Windows server 2008 r2, I have the SQL server installed in an ISO image and the windows server is on a VM workstation, but during the installation I got the following error "There are no SQL Server instances or shared features that can be updated on this computer." and there is no feature to select from, can anyone advice on this error , baring in mind that I am installing sql server 2008 r2 to be used for sharepoint 2013.
and when i generate the sql server feature report i got "none" for all the columns :-
[image]

BR

But since i am installing sql server for the first time inside my new server, so why i should already have any feature installed??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you do not have the proper SQL Server installation on that ISO file, but maybe just some update, like a Service Pack. That would explain the error message. Just an idea, though. You could try with another installation, should you have one. SQL Server Express would do for a test.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but how i can make sure that the ISO image is wrong ?

Comment: With the way installation goes. There is a standard SQL Server installation screen with all the processes, for example like this: http://www.sqlserverclub.com/essentialguides/how-to-install-sql-server-2008-step-by-step-guide.aspx
If you do not get any of the screens shown in here, you probably do not have the SQL Server installation at all on that ISO.

Comment: but instead if asking for a new iso imag, can i download the sql server 2008 r2 from this link http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30437 . and install it insdie my VM which have windows server 2008 r2??

Comment: No, this is just a Service Pack, see under "Details":
SQL Server 2008 R2 service packs are cumulative and can be used to upgrade all releases of SQL Server 2008 R2 to Service Pack 2. SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 2 contains Cumulative Update 1 to 5 from SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1.
You would have to find a standalone edition, for example, SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition

Comment: can you provide me with a link to download the required files.thnaks

Comment: You do realise that this version of SQL Server is not free, and that you have to obtain it via Microsoft`s site? Here is the link to the SQL Server 2012:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions/2012-editions/standard.aspx

Comment: yes sure I know that it is not for free, but I can install it and then provide the license key later, actually I did the same for the windows server 2008 . but I can not find a download link for sql server 2008 as the link u provide is for sql server 2012.. thnaks

Comment: I believe that the only version you can download is the current one at the provided link, the SQL Server 2012. Maybe Microsoft has a link via it`s Partner Source, so if you have an account with them, you could probably ask them for the 2008 version.